# DeploymentObjectProvider IIS extensibility

Tags: c#, iis

I'm building a custom provider for MSDeploy and followed some examples:

http://sedodream.com/2012/06/07/ASPNETProvidersAndSQLAzure.aspx

http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/06/19/msdeploy-custom-provider-to-execute-batch-files.aspx

But I can't get it to work somehow. I keep getting the following exception:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3>msdeploy -source:customFile=c:\test
\test.bat -verb=sync -dest:customFile=c:\test\test2.bat
Error Code: ERROR_PROVIDER_NOT_FOUND
More Information: The provider 'customFile' could not be found.  Learn more at:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_PROVIDER_NOT_FOUND.
Error count: 1.
```

Anyone got a working example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the answer:
http://blogs.iis.net/kateroh/archive/2009/06/19/msdeploy-custom-provider-to-execute-batch-files.aspx

I'm my case I had to add the files in: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\Extensibility